# Average of rows Mysql ignore zero values

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a problem with the function avg. I have a table like this and I would like to take the average of each row. I also have the zero in some cells and would like to avoid count them.

```
data    rep     val1    val2    val3
1       a       0       3       3      
2       a       1       4       0
3       a       1       1       1
4       a       1       3       0
```

And I would like this result

```
data    AVG
1       3
2       2.5
3       1
4       2
```

thank you

Comment: what is your SQL query?

Comment: Yes values are (0) and not null.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have at least one non-zero value:

```
SELECT data, (val1+val2+val3)/((val1!=0) + (val2!=0) + (val3!=0)) avg
  FROM **table_name**
```

I think divide by zero returns `null` see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_divide), depending on your db settings, so you could do:

```
SELECT data, COALESCE((val1+val2+val3)/((val1!=0) + (val2!=0) + (val3!=0)),0) avg
  FROM **table_name**
```

Any `null` values in a row will cause each query to always return `null` and `0` for the row respectively.

Comment: You should take care of the case that all values are zero :-)

Comment: Yes all values are zero.

Comment: +1 @Arth: You're right, you could copy a bit of the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_divide): *Division by zero produces a NULL result:*